# Алгоритм: добавление элемента в массив, если его там нет

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, javascript

На джаваскрипт. Есть входной массив слов, необходимо на его основе создать новый массив, но в него включить только неповторяющиеся слова, т.е. из

```
[раз, раз, два, раз, два, два, три, два, раз]
```

получить

```
[раз, два, три]
```

Пожалуйста, помогите советом или ткните ссылкой в готовую реализацию.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Определить массив
var a = new Array(0,4,6,4,10,0);

// Получить уникальные элементы (0,4,6,10)
var z = a.unique();
```

где

```
Array.prototype.unique = function () {
    var a = [];
    var l = this.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < l; j++) {
            if (this[i] === this[j]) {
                j = ++i;
            }
        }
        a.push(this[i]);
    }

    return a;
};
```

Comment: это уже стандартная ф-ция, или из библиотеки выше?..

Comment: вот же она ... Array.prototype.unique = function () {

Comment: отлично!!!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 7, 1];
var b = a.filter(function(element, index, array) {
  if (array.lastIndexOf(element) == index) return element
})

console.log("a="+a);
console.log("b="+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Underscore.js: [uniq](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#uniq).

И пожалуйста обратите внимание что при таком подходе ( а именно при дополнении встроенных объектов, в частности array ) нужно быть внимательным:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function () {
    var a = [];
    var l = this.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < l; j++) {
            if (this[i] === this[j]) {
                j = ++i;
            }
        }
        a.push(this[i]);
    }

    return a;
};
var ar = [1,2,3]
for(var i in ar){
    console.log(i)
}
```

//0
//1
//2
//unique

хотя это лечится использованием hasOwnProperty:

```
for(var i in ar){
    if(ar.hasOwnProperty(i))
        console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: мне бы так, чтобы не качать всю библиотек ради одной функции..

Comment: А что если дабавить свой toString() для unique() возвращяющий например undefined?